# Programmatically generate SSH Keypairs ( c# windows )

Tags: c#, ssh-keys, openssh

I'm looking to generate ssh keypairs in open SSH format via code within my web-app (hosted in windows machine) instead of having to manually create it using puttygen.

So, far I've not found any free library that can do this. (There doesn't seem to be a ssh-keygen equivalent for windows.) I am aware of the Cygwin route but I'm trying to avoid this as this would involve having to install cygwin on any servers hosting the app making it not ideal.

What are my options? Will I have to extract out the key-gen function from putty-gen-source and re-write it in c#?

Answer (score 0):

```
RSA rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

string publicPrivateKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
string publicOnlyKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
```

and then you can parse the XML using XML reader or XML document to get the value you want.